# Gradient field of a Function for 2 Variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

Initially I had something that looked like this, where I had something that was supposed to be a hemisphere and below was the gradient field. But I couldn't get the edges to go all the way down and look round. I'd always get calculation problems, and I'm always stuck with one octant.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=15cm,
    view={-30}{-20},
    domain=0.001:0.7,
    y domain=0.001:0.7,
    samples=20
    ]
      \addplot3[blue,/pgfplots/quiver,
        quiver/u=-x/(-x^2-y^2+1)^(-1/2),
        quiver/v=-y/(-x^2-y^2+1)^(-1/2),
        quiver/w=0,
        quiver/scale arrows=0.2,
        -stealth,samples=10] {0};
      \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.3] {(1-x^2-y^2)^(1/2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I'd want to make the output likes this geogebra applet: https://www.geogebra.org/m/QhfcuhqA (where I can plot the surface as well as plot the gradient field underneath) My goal is to have a kind of merge with this hemisphere and underneath will be the gradient field. It would be a dream if I could just type in the function for a cone or hyperbolic paraboloid and it would give me the gradient field underneath the surface, but it's okay if it's done manually as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [  samples=50,domain=0:360,y domain=0:90,
      xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2,zmin=0,zmax=1.2]
    \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.3]
    ({cos(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(y)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
    view={-30}{-20},
    domain=0.001:0.7,
    y domain=0.001:0.7,
    samples=20
    ]
      \addplot3[blue,/pgfplots/quiver,
        quiver/u=-x/(-x^2-y^2+1)^(-1/2),
        quiver/v=-y/(-x^2-y^2+1)^(-1/2),
        quiver/w=0,
        quiver/scale arrows=0.2,
        -stealth,samples=10] {0};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would think that LaTeX is not suitable for arbitrary input. It creates the most beautiful output, but not fully automatic -it alway needs a person to look at warnings/errors and general sanity of the output. I think that making the plot accept any function is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2,zmin=0,zmax=1.2]
    \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.3, samples=50,domain=0:360,y domain=0:90]
      ({cos(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(y)});
  \addplot3[blue,
  domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1,
  unbounded coords=discard,
  samples=21,
  quiver={every arrow/.append style={-{Latex[length=1.5pt]}}},
  quiver/u=-x/(-x^2-y^2+1)^(-1/2),
  quiver/v=-y/(-x^2-y^2+1)^(-1/2),
  quiver/w=0,
  quiver/scale arrows=0.2,
  x filter/.expression={(-x^2-y^2+1)>0?x:nan},
  y filter/.expression={(-x^2-y^2+1)>0?y:nan},
  x filter/.expression={x==0&&y==0?nan:x},
  ] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with quiver]

Comment: Thanks, this is petty much perfect, and the code seems easy enough to adapt to other functions and so that's a big help too.